# Why can't I build a pipe here in Prison Architect?

Tags: prison-architect

I'm trying to connect plumbing up for a toilet in a cell, but the game won't let me build a small or large pipe here. Is there a reason why?

[image: My utilities layout]

Comment: Usually only does that when a tile is too blocked to work (workers can "cheat" one tile into walls or objects, so it'd be surrounded from all sides).  What's in the way?

Comment: Are you perhaps out of cash?

Comment: Are you playing one of the scenarios? They have areas where you can't build anything to avoid messing up any scripted sequences. Doesn't look like it, though.

Comment: Nope, have plenty of money, and it's not a scenario, just a new prison. Maybe the toilet is in the way?

Comment: Can you upload your save game somewhere so we can take a look? You can search the file if you know the (x,y) location of the map and see what may be causing the problem.

Comment: Have you searched that particular toilet for tunnels?

Comment: Not sure what the issue was, but I saved and reloaded my prison and I seem to be able to build a pipe there now.

Comment: Was the cell occupied by a gang member? Gang controlled areas (including their cells) cannot be edited or dezoned.

Comment: @Studoku That's possible! There was someone occupying the cell at the time (only just built, so I doubt there were tunnels there, and I searched it but no tunnels). Unfortunately, I didn't save at that point, and the problem is gone now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely playing with gangs enabled. You are not able to build in cells or rooms occupied by a gang. This sadly also means that when a gang member is assigned to a cell while you are still adding the infrastructure, you are no longer able to build that as well.

Gain visibility on the cell if you don't already have that by selecting a guard and right-clicking in the cell. Click the prisoner, and right-click on a different cell that has no gang-member in it. The prisoner is transfered, allowing you to build in that cell again.

The following images show the issue with in-game screenshots.

[When one is unable to build pipes through a cell... http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/396676045196404958/8D886A8BD5C5AA4CBAC4A24DEF60AC182BA84664/?interpolation=lanczos-none&output-format=jpeg&output-quality=95&fit=inside|1024:576&composite-to=*,*|1024:576&background-color=black](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/396676045196404958/8D886A8BD5C5AA4CBAC4A24DEF60AC182BA84664/?interpolation=lanczos-none&output-format=jpeg&output-quality=95&fit=inside|1024:576&composite-to=*,*|1024:576&background-color=black)

[...that cell might be occupied with a gang member http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/396676045196404185/ED98E76FF0198CB0E2C933AE4E8F6EAAB44CCCC9/?interpolation=lanczos-none&output-format=jpeg&output-quality=95&fit=inside|1024:576&composite-to=*,*|1024:576&background-color=black](http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/396676045196404185/ED98E76FF0198CB0E2C933AE4E8F6EAAB44CCCC9/?interpolation=lanczos-none&output-format=jpeg&output-quality=95&fit=inside|1024:576&composite-to=*,*|1024:576&background-color=black)

Comment: Not 100% this is what caused my problem, but it makes the most sense, as I wasn't able to build in that room at all. And yes, I am playing with gangs enabled.